# Android Emulator cannot connect to network

Tags: android, connection, emulation

this is a very unusual problem. I am having trouble getting an Android Emulator to just connect to the internet. I know it is just supposed to "work" after you install it, but so far I am running into difficulties. What is interesting is that I have installed and run the emulator on another machine where the internet worked perfectly. The only differences are these. The machine with problems is a WIN XP 32bit machine. The internet worked on a WIN 7 64bit machine.
Now this is not an issue with an app not seeing the internet. The emulator simply cannot see any network. I've been researching this issue for awhile and have been unable to resolve it. The forum I found that perfectly matched my issue ended with a strange fix that I have not had any success with. [Emulator unable to connect to internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104675/emulator-unable-to-connect-to-internet) (the issue was resolved by disabling you USB WiFi dongle). I don't know whether I have such a dongle on my android emulator (have tried to find it to disable it with no luck).

I have also tried adding the old  line to my hello, Android's manifest file with no luck.

I've also tried various SD card sizes up to 3000Mb in size!
I've tried nearly all the emulators available on my AVD manager from 1.5 up to 2.3.
I've also tried adding firewall exceptions then tried turning off the firewall.

any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems once I went to SDK 2.3. The answer to my question

[Upgraded to SDK 2.3 - now no emulators have connectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376553/upgraded-to-sdk-2-3-now-no-emulators-have-connectivity)

fixed it for me.

It doesn't seem to like systems that have 'obtain DNS automatically' set, so try setting it to a public DNS

Comment: thanks for the response, but I am currently using the most recent SDK. Turns out the problem was my workplace, tried emulator at home and was able to connect to the internet!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer. I have to admit the problem was on my end, the building that I work in was causing the problems. Once I took the laptop home and tried Android there I could reach the internet (thought I had already tried that otherwise I wouldn't have posted here). So sorry about that and just a lesson for anyone having connectivity issues to consider where they are connecting from first.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem, my emulator cannot connect internet, even the emulator browser cannot connect properly,

> close emulator & eclipse -> open task manager -> go to process tab ->
>   search adb.exe -> **end process adb.exe** -> re-start the eclipse

It works for me.